# Declaring default constructor while invoking base class constructor

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I am trying to implement the concept of invoking base class constructor and inheritance.I have written the following code but it is giving error when I don't declare the default constructor for class A, I wonder why am I getting the error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int a;
    public:
    A() {} //Default Constructor
    A(int x)
    {
        a=x;cout<<a;
        cout<<"A Constructor\n";
    }
};
class B: virtual public A
{
    int b;
    public:
    B(int x)
    {
        b=x;cout<<b;
        cout<<"B Constructor\n";
    }
};
class C: virtual public A
{
    int c;
    public:
    C(int x)
    {
        c=x;cout<<c;
        cout<<"C Constructor\n";
    }
};
class D: public B,public C
{
    int d;
    public:
    D(int p,int q,int r,int s):A(p),B(q),C(r)
    {
        d=s;cout<<d;
        cout<<"D Constructor\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    D d(1,2,3,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which error specifically?

Comment: The `A` default constructor is used implicitly in classes `B` and `C`. I'm not sure of the formal because I remember this question popping up years ago, and possibly the answer was that in a case like this the implicit initializations in `B` and `C` should be regarded as non-existent. Anyway these initializations are effectively ignored in your use case, because a virtual base class is initialized from the most derived class, in your case `D`. Yes, the concept of virtual inheritance in C++ is a bit unclean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, let's simplify things and forget about existence of classes `C` an `D`.

If you construct an object of type `B` as

```
B b(10);
```

it will use `B::B(int)`. In the implementation of `B::B(int)`, the `A` part of `B` has to be initialized somehow. You have:

```
B(int x)
{
    b=x;cout<<b;
    cout<<"B Constructor\n";
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
B(int x) : A()
{
    b=x;cout<<b;
    cout<<"B Constructor\n";
}
```

Since `A` does not have a default constructor, the compiler correctly reports that as an error.

You could fix that by using:

```
B(int x) : A(0)
{
    b=x;cout<<b;
    cout<<"B Constructor\n";
}
```

If would like to be able to pass another value to `A(int)` from `B`'s constructor, you need to allow the user to construct a `B` using two arguments.

```
B(int x, int y = 0) : A(y)
{
    b=x;cout<<b;
    cout<<"B Constructor\n";
}
```

Comment: However, class `B` is not used as a most derived class in the OP's code. One could argue that support for separate compilation practically requires that that case does not have special rules. But I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, `B(int)` needs to be handled correctly regardless of whether `B` is instantiated or `D` is instantiated.

Comment: @R.Sahu: Note that it *does different things* in the case of B as most derived class, and the case of B as a base class. In the latter case it does not necessarily call the `A` constructor. That's called from the most derived class. One way to effect the different behaviors is to generate code for the B constructor that performs a dynamic check of whether to call `A()`. Another way is to emit the call to `A()` at the place of instantion of B as most derived class. In the latter case the linker error can be avoided. The question about what the standard allows/guarantees is therefore open.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, True. It's not clear to me whether the OP understands that. However, when `B(int)` is processed by the compiler, it has no way of knowing whether a `B` will be instantiated or not. It has to process `B(int)` with the possibility that `B` will be instantiated.

Comment: The possibility that `B` may be instantiated does not mean that `B`'s constructor must have code that calls `A()`. It's trivial to avoid that, if the standard requires avoiding it. So this is not a question of technical necessity: it's a question of what the standard says, or not.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, how else will an instantiation of `B` initialize its `A` subobject?

Comment: One way is as described already, *as if* at each point where `B` is instantiated as a most derived class, the compiler generates an initialization that calls `A()` (it has to happen first, by the init rules) and if that succeeds, the `B` constructor implementation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, That's why `B(int)`, more generally, all the constructors of `B`, must initialize the `A` subject using a valid constructor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I am sure you know these details. There is something else that you are trying to communicate and I am failing to catch the drift.

Comment: Not sure what/where the gap is. The main point is that `A` is a virtual base class, and as such it is initialized *only* from the most derived class. Other apparent initializations up the base class chain, even if explicitly expressed, are ignored. Another main point is that where `B` is instantiated as a most derived class, it is complete class. The compiler is free to inline at each such point the code that calls `A()`: it just has to match that with `B` constructor machine code that doesn't. With this technique there would be no calls to `A()` in the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont call the constructor of the superclass in the subclass, the superclass must have a default constructor, because if you want to create an instance of B, there will be automatically created an instance of the superclass, which is not possible if there is no default constructor.