# Use of deleted function

Tags: c++, deleted-functions

Hello newbie programmer here. Please help me. What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Konut {

public:

    int yas;
    int metrekare;
    int kat;
    string isitma_turu;

    Konut(int a, int b, int c, string d) {
        yas = a;
        metrekare = b;
        kat = c;
        isitma_turu = d;
    }

    void yazdir() {
        cout << " Yas " << yas << " Metrekare " << metrekare << " Kat " << kat << " Isitma Turu " << isitma_turu << endl;
    }
};

class Ciftlik_evi :public Konut {

public:
    int Hayvan_sayisi;
    int Merkeze_uzaklik;


    getFiyat(int fiyat) {
        yas* Merkeze_uzaklik * 1000000;
        return fiyat;

    }
};

class Villa :public Konut {
public:
    int havuz_metrekaresi;
    int Merkeze_uzaklik;

    getFiyat(int fiyat) {
        yas* Merkeze_uzaklik * 1000000;
        return fiyat;
    }
};

int main() {

    Ciftlik_evi c1;
    c1.Hayvan_sayisi = 232;
    c1.Merkeze_uzaklik = 6789;

    c1.getfiyat();
}
```

```
||=== Build: Debug in Salaklık (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp||In member function 'int Ciftlik_evi::getFiyat(int)':|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|34|warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp||In member function 'int Villa::getFiyat(int)':|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|46|warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|54|error: use of deleted function 'Ciftlik_evi::Ciftlik_evi()'|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|26|note: 'Ciftlik_evi::Ciftlik_evi()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|26|error: no matching function for call to 'Konut::Konut()'|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|14|note: candidate: 'Konut::Konut(int, int, int, std::__cxx11::string)'|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|14|note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|5|note: candidate: 'Konut::Konut(const Konut&)'|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|5|note: candidate: 'Konut::Konut(Konut&&)'|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Salaklık\main.cpp|58|error: 'class Ciftlik_evi' has no member named 'getfiyat'; did you mean 'getFiyat'?|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: `Ciftlik_evi c1;` attempts to create an instance of `Ciftlik_evi` initialized with a default consturctor - but class `Ciftlik_evi` doesn't in fact have a default constructor: none is provided by the user, and the implicit default constructor can't be declared because the base class `Konut` doesn't have one either.

Comment: If you want Ciftlik_evi to have a default constructor that is synthesized by the compiler for you, you could do `Ciftlik_evi() = default;` in the class definition.  And base class `Konut() = default;` (thanks Igor!).

Comment: @Eljay Except that the compiler would be unable to synthesize one, as the base class lacks one. And if the base class had a default constructor, then `Ciftlik_evi() = default;` line wouldn't have been necessary.

Comment: I cant understand please show on code

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894931/declaring-default-constructor-while-invoking-base-class-constructor